# Freeware-Tool/Plugin for live coding with collaborators

Tags: gratis, ide, collaboration, workflow

With `tmux` multiple users can connect to a window and see what people type even before execution of the command.

```
apt install tmux
tmux new -s mywindow
tmux attach -t mywindow
```

I've started using Visual Studio Code with Remote SSH: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh
With that you have the benefit of developing on your local machine but executing your program on a remote. That is especially useful if you are e.g. utilizing the GPIO of a Raspberry Pi.

I was wondering if there is an IDE/plugin that allows you to code on a remote server + immediately showing what you are writing live when someone connects to the remote.
I do not wish to screenshare because it consumes a lot of bandwidth and the quality can be bad. Furthermore the user cannot edit. I also do not want to share my PC because then I cannot do different things off-screen and there is the security aspect.

I know this question has been asked before. However the questions are quite old and I wonder if new tools/plugins have emerged/gotten popular. Furthermore a lot of the answers point towards paid tools.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Reading between the lines: am I correct you're looking for a free (as in free-beer, i.e. no money involved, but not necessarily as in free-speech, i.e. libre+open-source) software that runs on Linux? Or rather a web app accessible via browser?

Comment: Can be either. The crucial thing being is that multiple clients can collaborate simultaneously and see live changes in the code before the code files are saved.